# How to import functions that I created at web worker?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-worker, sheetjs

I am new to Web Worker, and right now what I am trying to do is import my function that I have created under the **workerCode** in Web Worker, but neither "**import**" nor "**importScript**" work; only the **XLSX** library is working fine, but the rest is not.

Could you help me figure out how to do this?

```
export const consolidateWorkerV2 = () => {
 const workerCode = `
 /* Load standalone script from CDN */
 import * as XLSX from "https://cdn.sheetjs.com/xlsx-0.20.1/package/xlsx.mjs";
 import getDataRange from "../shared/util/GetDataRange";
 import modifyWorksheet from "../shared/util/modifyWorksheet.js";
 import headerStyling from "../shared/util/headerStyling";

 self.addEventListener('message', async (e) => {
  try {
    const files = e.data.files;
    const newWorkbook = XLSX.utils.book_new();
    console.log("message received from main thread");
    for (const [index, item] of files.entries()) {
      const file = item.file;
      const filename = item.file.name
      const data = await item.file.arrayBuffer();
      const workbook = XLSX.read(data);
      
      for (const sheetName of workbook.SheetNames) {
        if (newWorkbook.SheetNames.includes(journalType)) {
          const duplicateSheetName = workbook.SheetNames[0];
          const newWorksheet = newWorkbook.Sheets[journalType];
          const dupWorksheet = getDataRange(workbook.Sheets[duplicateSheetName]);
          const OPTIONS = { raw: false, defval: "", };
          const parsedDupWorksheet = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(dupWorksheet, OPTIONS);
          const updatedWorksheet = modifyWorksheet(dupWorksheet, parsedDupWorksheet, duplicateSheetName, journalType, reportDate);
          const newData = updatedWorksheet.map((row) => Object.values(row));
          XLSX.utils.sheet_add_aoa(newWorksheet, newData, { origin: -1, skipHeader: true });
        } else {
          // if no existing sheet name, then add new sheet
          for (const sheetName of workbook.SheetNames) {
            const worksheet = workbook.Sheets[sheetName];
            const worksheetData = getDataRange(worksheet);
            const parsedWorksheet = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(worksheet, { raw: false, defval: "", });
            const updatedWorksheet = modifyWorksheet(worksheetData, parsedWorksheet, sheetName, journalType, reportDate);
            const styledSheet = headerStyling(updatedWorksheet);
            XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(newWorkbook, styledSheet, journalType);
          }
        }
      }
    }
    
    const consolidateFilename = namingConvention("Consolidated_Final_Report", date);
    const excelBuffer = XLSX.write(newWorkbook, { bookType: "xlsx", type: "array", });
    const blob = new File([excelBuffer], fileName + ".xlsx");
    postMessage({ blob: blob });   
  } catch(e) {
    /* Pass the error message back */
    postMessage({ error: String(e.message || e).bold() });
  }
}, false);
`;

  const blob = new Blob([workerCode], { type: "text/javascript" });
  const worker = new Worker(URL.createObjectURL(blob), { type: "module" });
  return worker;
};
```

Comment: Why are you using a blob rather than using a separate worker file? I suspect the problem (well, one of the problems) is that relative paths aren't resolving the way you expect as a result of using a blob.

Comment: Separately, on the web platform without the intervention of a bundler, etc., you must provide the file extensions -- that is, the actual filenames -- of the modules you import. So: `from "../shared/util/GetDataRange.js"` not `from "../shared/util/GetDataRange"`, etc. The native import mechanism doesn't do any guessing about the actual names of resources.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, I was following the documentation of the Sheet JS and suggest declaring that way. So I thought this was the right way of doing it? Here's the reference: https://docs.sheetjs.com/docs/demos/bigdata/worker/

Comment: That page shows multiple options. Just before the example using a blob it has the more usual example of using a URL: `const worker = new Worker(url_to_worker_script, { type: "module" });`. So for instance: `const worker = new Worker("./worker.js", { type: "module" });` That's what I'd recommend, since then you can use relative imports without playing games. :-) See my answer for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two issues:

1. You must include the full filename of the module you import via `import` or `importScripts` when there's no bundler involved; the native web platform doesn't try to guess at file extensions. So you'd need:

   ```
   import getDataRange from "../shared/util/GetDataRange.js";
   // −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^
   ```

   ...assuming that's the full path of the resource.
2. I can't find a specific citation for it, but I believe when you load a worker via a blob, you can't use relative imports. Four possible mututally-exclusive solutions for that:

   1. Don't use a Blob. Put the worker code in its own file and use the URL to that file:

      ```
      const worker = new Worker("./path/to/worker.js", { type: "module" });
      ```

      This is the simple and easy answer.
   2. Alternatively, use absolute imports as you did with the `XLSX` library if you only need to run this code on a single site. For example:

      ```
      import getDataRange from "https://example.com/shared/util/GetDataRange.js";
      ```

      Or similar.
   3. Or, modify the `workerCode` to replace the relative paths with absolute ones before creating the Blob:

      ```
      let workerCode = /*...*/;
      const shared = new URL("../shared", location.href).toString();
      workerCode = workerCode.replace(/from "\.\.\/shared/g, `from ${shared}`);
      // ...build the worker
      ```
   4. Or use `self.origin` to get the origin within the worker (a quick test suggests this works on Chromium, Firefox, and Safari) and use [dynamic import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/import).

      ```
      const getDataRange = (await import(new URL("../shared/util/GetDataRange", self.origin).toString())).default;
      ```

      I suspect any of the other three solutions are better than this one, but again, it did seem to work on the major browsers.

Comment: 1.0m • 189 • 1945 • 1893    One million  , I think you should get some sort of award for that.. :)

Comment: @Keith - Thanks! Sadly, SE Inc. doesn't agree. They and the meta guardians even [stopped people doing congratulatory posts on MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/424359/we-are-no-longer-allowing-congratulatory-posts-on-meta-for-users-reaching-1-mill) but then compromised on [a single catchall](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/424425/the-stack-overflow-1-million-points-club).  Long gone are the days when SE Inc used to at least throw some swag at contributors (I still have three mugs). Still, that's not why people like you and I do it. The work is its own reward. :-D

Comment: @T.J. Crowder, thank you so much! I reworked by not using the blob and doing number 1 from the number 2 example. Then rewrite the script from my example into just **self.onmessage = async (message) => {...}** instead so I could import all the functions. Now it is working perfectly!!